# @ContextConfiguration in test if parent has @ContextHierarchy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test, junit-jupiter

I have tests for class, that uses `RestTemplate`. Now I need to write another test for the similar class.
I've decided to move `@ContextHierarchy` to separate interface like below

```java
@ContextHierarchy({
        @ContextConfiguration(classes = {
                ObjectMapperConfiguration.class, // ObjectMapper
                HttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class // MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
        }),
        @ContextConfiguration(classes = HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.class),
        @ContextConfiguration(classes = RestTemplateAutoConfiguration.class), // RestTemplate builder
        @ContextConfiguration(classes = {
                RestTemplateConfig.class, // finally RestTemplate
                // tested service was HERE
        })
})
public interface RestTemplateTest {
}

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestedService.class) // now it is HERE
public class RestTest implements RestTemplateTest {
}
```

The problem is that code about doesn't work. I receive error message from Spring that `TestedService` cannot be created because there's no bean of type `RestTemplate`.

If I move `TestedService` back to `@ContextHierarchy` then everything is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's turned out that to make everything to work RestTemplateTest must be a **class**, not an interface